# scala sbt - how to point to local scala and akka on my disk

Tags: scala, sbt

I am a little confused with the build.sbt for scala. I downloaded the scala library and placed it into /usr/share/scala and akka into my ~/apps/bin folder. I copied this build.sbt from some where.

```
name := "AkkaTest"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.10.0"
resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/" 
libraryDependencies +=  "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor" % "2.0.4"
```

First time I ran it, it seemed to be downloading the entire akka and scala libraries from the net.  No idea where it is putting the downloaded content either.  This makes me very uneasy not knowing what's being downloaded and where to on my disk. Also, each time I upgrade, I assume it will do the whole download thing and store multiple versions of scala and akka somewhere (where is it?).

Is there any way to point build.sbt to the scala and akka folders that I know about and can change later.  This would also help if I am working offline rather than build.sbt always checking with online repositories.

Thanks.

Comment: Tip: by default sbt puts everything it has resolved into `~/.ivy2/cache`.

Comment: Thanks. I do see a lot of stuff in there. Some day I'll purge the whole thing (as suggested in next answer) and let sbt re-download.

Comment: These days (SBT 0.10.x and later) there's pretty much only one reason to have a stand-alone Scala installation, and that is for running a stock REPL outside of any project. I do have it installed for that purpose, but interestingly enough, about the only time I use it anymore is to illustrate something for a coworker or to try out extremely simple constructs. Otherwise, I have a "scratch" SBT project called "scribble" in which I accumulate one-off bits of code. It's easier to edit them in IDEA and use SBT's `console` command to exercise them.

Comment: You can always make it an unmanaged dependency by dropping jars in the lib/ folder of your project.  You shouldn't do this except as a last resort, and certainly not out of vague unease.  If you want to cut a distribution later that includes all your jars and doesn't need to dig into your ivy cache for the classpath, sbt gives you a number of options, from "retrieveManaged := true" to uber-jar packers such as the assembly plugin.

Comment: I think this is a really good question; sbt seems great for getting things 'just working', but IMHO it shouldn't do the job of a package manager - i.e. managing _system_ dependencies. But everyone just seems to accept this. I wish it would, _out of the box_ check for libraries in your system paths before going and downloading the whole internet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SBT uses a dependency management system called [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/), which (like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html), another dependency manager) stores downloaded artifacts in a repository.  (Ivy, to `~/.ivy2`.)  If you're concerned about disk space, you can periodically purge subsets of these directories (and download everything you need again).  I also exclude them from backups.

You can read more about Ivy [here](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/).